# Excel VBA: Is there a way to reference an instance of a class stored in a dictionary?

Tags: excel, vba, class, dictionary, instance

I currently have instances of classes stored using the data structure presented in the image below. Each `-List` item is a dictionary and each `-Info` item is an instance of a class.

[image: Data Structure]

I read elsewhere that if you `Set` an instance variable equal to another instance, it just references the original instance. Is this correct?

I have been able to create a reference for `fileInfo(1)` (in the image) using the following code.

```
Dim prflInfo As File_Info
Set prflInfo = New File_Info
Set prflInfo = fileList.Items(0)
```

I have attempted to reference the branchInfo instance using the following code, but I get a `Run-time error 13: Type mismatch` when I attempt to do so.

```
Dim prbrInfo As Branch_Info
With prflInfo
    Set prbrInfo = New Branch_Info
    brKey = .getbrKey(0)
    Set prbrInfo = .getbrItem(brKey)
End With
```

Edit: Included below is the code for the File_Info class. All other classes follow this basic model.

```
'Class Module: File_Info

'Initialise class variables
Private pfileID As Integer
Private pfilePath As String
Private pfileName As String

Private pbranchList As Scripting.Dictionary

'Declare variantcopy subroutine
Private Declare Sub VariantCopy Lib "OleAut32" (pvarDest As Any, pvargSrc As Any)

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pbranchList = New Scripting.Dictionary
End Sub

Public Property Let fileID(pfileIDi As Variant)
    pfileID = pfileIDi
End Property
Public Property Get fileID() As Variant
    fileID = pfileID
End Property

Public Property Let filePath(pfilePathi As Variant)
    pfilePath = pfilePathi
End Property
Public Property Get filePath() As Variant
    filePath = pfilePath
End Property

Public Property Let fileName(pfileNamei As Variant)
    pfileName = pfileNamei
End Property
Public Property Get fileName() As Variant
    fileName = pfileName
End Property

Public Sub addbrConn(branch As Branch_Info)
    pbranchList.Add branch.branchID, branch.brConn
    Debug.Print "addbrConn ID: " & branch.branchID
End Sub

Public Sub addBranch(branch As Branch_Info)
    pbranchList.Add branch.branchID, branch
    Debug.Print pbranchList.Count
End Sub

Public Function countbrList()
    countbrList = pbranchList.Count
End Function

Public Function getbrKey(Key As Variant)
    getbrKey = pbranchList.Keys(Key)
End Function

Public Function getbrItem(Key As Variant)
    getbrItem = GetByRefVariant(pbranchList.Items(Key))
End Function

Public Sub dpbrList()
    With pbranchList
        Debug.Print pbranchList.Count
        For k = 1 To pbranchList.Count
            Debug.Print .Keys(k - 1), .Items(k - 1)
        Next k
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub updbrList(branch As Branch_Info)
    Dim branchID As String
    branchID = branch.branchID

    If pbranchList.exists(branchID) Then
        pbranchList.Remove (branchID)
        pbranchList.Add branchID, branch
        Debug.Print "Complete: " & branchID & " added."
    Else
        Debug.Print "Error: " & branchID & "does not exist."
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetByRefVariant(ByRef var As Variant) As Variant
    VariantCopy GetByRefVariant, var
End Function
```

Is there a way to reference the branchInfo class, to make it easier to extract the data within it?

Thanks!

Eeshwar

Comment: There is, but without the code as to the class properties and methods, it would be hard for me to respond to your question.

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for updating the question to include the image inline. I've added the File_Info class information. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I do things differently in that I iterate through the keys list using a `For ... each` loop rather than referring to an item number.  Here is a snippet that works using two levels.

You can ignore the lines where the property values are written to an array, but they were part of the original code.

`cf.Dependents` is a dictionary of `cDependents` within the `cFamily` object

```
'Declarations in Main Module

Dim dF As Dictionary, cF As cFamily, cD As cDependents
Dim I As Long, J As Long
Dim V As Variant, W As Variant

...

For Each V In dF
    I = I + 1
    Set cF = dF(V)
    With cF
        vRes(I, 1) = .FirstName
        vRes(I, 2) = .LastName
        vRes(I, 3) = .Birthdate

        J = 2
        For Each W In .Dependents
            J = J + 2
            Set cD = .Dependents(W)
            With cD
                vRes(I, J) = .Relation
                vRes(I, J + 1) = .DepName
            End With
        Next W
    End With
Next V
```

Note that in the sequence, as you show in your question:

```
set Obj = new Obj
set Obj = myClass(0)
```

the first line is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it is possible to use  simple `VBA.Collection`, here example for the `FileList` and `BranchList`. In this example `List` classes have `Items` and `Info` classes have reference to `List` where `List` is wrapper for a `VBA.Collection`. HTH

For more reading have a look e.g. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262338(v=vs.60).aspx).

> FileList Class

```
Option Explicit

Private m_fileInfoCollection As FileInfoCollection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_fileInfoCollection = New FileInfoCollection
End Sub

Public Property Get Items() As FileInfoCollection
    Set Items = m_fileInfoCollection
End Property
```

> FileInfo Class

```
Option Explicit

Private m_branchList As BranchList

Private m_fileID As Integer

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_branchList = New BranchList
End Sub

Public Property Get FileID() As Integer
    FileID = m_fileID
End Property

Public Property Let FileID(ByVal vNewValue As Integer)
    m_fileID = vNewValue
End Property

Public Property Get BranchList() As BranchList
    Set BranchList = m_branchList
End Property
```

> FileInfoCollection Class

```
Option Explicit

Private m_collection As VBA.Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_collection = New VBA.Collection
End Sub

Public Sub Add(ByVal newItem As FileInfo)
    m_collection.Add newItem, CStr(newItem.FileID)
End Sub

Public Function ItemByKey(ByVal key As String) As FileInfo
    Set ItemByKey = m_collection(key)
End Function

Public Function ItemByIndex(ByVal index As Long) As FileInfo
    Set ItemByIndex = m_collection(index)
End Function

Public Function Count() As Long
    Count = m_collection.Count
End Function
```

> BranchList Class

```
Option Explicit

Private m_branchInfoCollection As BranchInfoCollection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_branchInfoCollection = New BranchInfoCollection
End Sub

Public Property Get Items() As BranchInfoCollection
    Set Items = m_branchInfoCollection
End Property
```

> BranchInfo Class

```
Option Explicit

Private m_branchID As Integer

Public Property Get branchID() As Integer
    branchID = m_branchID
End Property

Public Property Let branchID(ByVal vNewValue As Integer)
    m_branchID = vNewValue
End Property
```

> BranchInfoCollection Class

```
Option Explicit

Private m_collection As VBA.Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_collection = New VBA.Collection
End Sub

Public Sub Add(ByVal newItem As BranchInfo)
    m_collection.Add newItem, CStr(newItem.branchID)
End Sub

Public Function ItemByKey(ByVal key As String) As BranchInfo
    Set ItemByKey = m_collection(key)
End Function

Public Function ItemByIndex(ByVal index As Long) As BranchInfo
    Set ItemByIndex = m_collection(index)
End Function

Public Function Count() As Long
    Count = m_collection.Count
End Function
```

> Standard Module

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    ' Fill
    Dim bi As BranchInfo
    Set bi = New BranchInfo
    bi.branchID = 111

    Dim fi As FileInfo
    Set fi = New FileInfo
    fi.FileID = 222
    fi.BranchList.Items.Add bi

    Dim fl As FileList
    Set fl = New FileList
    fl.Items.Add fi

    ' Get
    Dim fi1 As FileInfo
    Set fi1 = fl.Items.ItemByIndex(1)

    Dim bi1 As BranchInfo
    Set bi1 = fi1.BranchList.Items(1)
End Sub
```